# displaying python list of lists in a jinja template

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I wrote an application where a user enters a number, and the application computes the pythagorean triples of that number.

I am having problems putting the triples in a list and displaying them in an html table.
Server Side Method:

```
 def post(self):
    allTriples = []
    c = int(self.request.get('c'))
    print('c: ' + str(c))
    for i in range(1, c):
        for j in range(1, c):
            for k in range(1, c):
                i2 = i*i
                j2 = j*j
                k2 = k*k
                if ((i2 + j2) == k2) and (i < j):
                    singleTriple = []
                    singleTriple.append(i)
                    singleTriple.append(j)
                    singleTriple.append(k)
                    allTriples.append(singleTriple)
    d = {
        'allTriples' : allTriples,
    }
    print(allTriples)
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('triples.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(d))
```

Here's an output of the list of lists when 15 is entered

```
[[3, 4, 5], [5, 12, 13], [6, 8, 10]]
```

Jinja Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pythagorean Triples</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
    {% for triple in allTriples %}
        <p>triple</p>
        <tr>
            {% for val in triple %}
                <td>val</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The html shows just the words "val" where the numbers should be.

Comment: I think you just need to replace val with {{val}} in the for loop.

Comment: and similarly replace `<p>triple</p>` with `<p>{{ triple }}</p>` ('tho I assume that's just for debugging)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just typo in your template code
you should use `<td>{{val}}</td>` instead of `<td>val</td>`